# Why won't my java program add sound even with .wav file?

Tags: java, audio, javasound

I am making a program just to test around with sound. To make it I was following a video which a link to can be found here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VMSTTg5EEnY. However, when I run it, it makes a frame with a button, but the button doesn't do anything. What is the problem?

```
   package RefrenceCode;
import sun.audio.AudioData;
import sun.audio.AudioPlayer;
import sun.audio.AudioStream;
import sun.audio.ContinuousAudioDataStream;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Sound {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(200,200);
        JButton button = new JButton("Click me");
        frame.add(button);
        button.addActionListener(new AL());
        frame.show(true);
    }
    public static class AL implements ActionListener{
        public final void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            music();
        }}
    public static void music(){
        AudioPlayer BGP = AudioPlayer.player;
        AudioStream BGM;
        AudioData MD;
        ContinuousAudioDataStream loop = null;
        try {
            //InputStream test = new FileInputStream("C:\\ wiiMusic.wav");
            //BGM = new AudioStream(test);
            BGM = new AudioStream(new FileInputStream("wiiMusic.wav"));
            MD = BGM.getData();
            loop = new ContinuousAudioDataStream(MD);
        }catch(IOException error) {}
        BGP.start(loop);
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) `import sun.audio.ContinuousAudioDataStream;` **Do not use** classes under the `com.sun` hierarchy. The [javasound info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javasound/info) shows how to load and play a `Clip`. 2) `catch(IOException error) {}` Don't ignore exceptions! They inform us exactly what went wrong. Unless logging is implemented, at least call `Throwable.printStackTrace()` 3) Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it's an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) & use it consistently.

Comment: Thank you, I never used try and catch so I didn't know how it works and it, in fact, does show an error. The naming convention was just from the video, I usually do follow conventions. Lastly, the file is downloaded onto my computer and was converted from a youtube link. So how can I use clip without the url?

Comment: *"..it, in fact, does show an error"* .. what is the error? Always copy/paste error and exception output! Include it as an [edit] to the question & use code formatting.

Comment: By error I went it catches in the try and catch, I told it to print error if it catches so that's what I went

Comment: *"I told it to print error"* Then [edit] the question to show that in the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obsolete tutorials seem to be a growing problem!

I am interpreting the OP comment as asking the following question: how to address and load an audio file that is local, i.e., packaged with the java program, not access remotely.

The link provided by Andrew Thompson in the comments is useful, but it does not have an example of addressing a self-contained audio file. I don't know how to edit it to include an example. The Oracle Sound Trail Tutorial is similarly deficient, for whatever reason.

First off, the URL form for creating the `AudioInputStream` is most usually best:

```
AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(url);
```

Why? Because it has the additional capability of locating resources that are packed in a jar, whereas the File system cannot.

I think the most usual practice for accessing a self-contained audio resource is to make use of the [ClassLoader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource-java.lang.String-) for a Class that you are sure will be part of your project. The address of the audio resource is then given as a relative address to the address of this class.

For example, let's say you have the class "MySound" in your project. If the audio files are in the same folder or package, the relative addressing scheme would look like this:

```
URL beepURL = MySound.class.getResource("beep.wav");
```

If the audio file was in a subfolder or subpackage of the one where MySound is located, such as "/audio", the command would be as follows:

```
URL beepURL = MySound.class.getResource("audio/beep.wav");
```

The basic HTML rules for specifying relative addresses should work. That includes symbols such as ".." for addressing a parent folder or package.

For example, if you have a package named res/audio that is adjacent to the package holding MySound

```
URL beepURL = MySound.class.getResource("../res/audio/beep.wav");
```

File structure for above example:

```
src/com.mydomainname.myproject/utils/MySound 
src/com.mydomainname.myproject/res/audio/beep.wav
```

There are different rules that apply if you start the url address with "/" as is "/beep.wav". The documentation refers to this as an "absolute" form. I have not used it in my own coding, so I will not risk explaining it in a faulty way.

For the [JavaSound Info Page example](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javasound/info) we might edit these lines as follows:

```
    URL url = LoopSound.class.getResource("leftright.wav");
    Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
    AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream( url );
    clip.open(ais);
```

This assumes that leftright.wav is located in the same package as LoopSound.

Comment: `MySound.class.getResource(..)` This can be called from a `main` method where it will get the wrong (i.e. bootstrap) class loader and fail. For that reason I prefer `this.getClass().getResource(..)` which can only be done inside a class that will be using the context class loader. *"There are different rules that apply if you start the url address with "/" as is "/beep.wav"."* I far prefer this form, which works from the 'root' of the classpath. More details in  the [info. page for embedded resource](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info).

Comment: Sounds good, Andrew. Thanks for adding the embedded resource link. I find myself just sticking with the first solution that worked for me, but it is good to have explanations of other ways to do this.

Comment: Thank you so much this was very useful. Sorry for not being that specific it is my fist question on here

Comment: No problem Alex. Sometimes figuring out the right question is more than half the battle! Welcome to Stack Overflow!