# Music not playing in .JAR-file

Tags: java, jar, fxml, embedded-resource, javasound

I'm trying to make a song play when opening the .JAR-file. It works fine in Netbeans but when opening the .Jar-file only the button for scenechange and the images on those scenes show.

In the controller for the FXML i've initialized a Thread for playing the song:

```
@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    PlaySong ps = new PlaySong();
    Thread thread = new Thread(ps);
    thread.start();

}
```

This calls the class with the thread which should play the song:

```
public class PlaySong implements Runnable {

@Override
public void run() {
    playSong();
}

static void playSong(){
    try{
        AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File("/src/maanedsdag2/AssetsLibrary/James Smith  - Just the Way You Are.wav").getAbsoluteFile());
        Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        clip.open(audioInputStream);
        clip.start();

        Thread.sleep(clip.getMicrosecondLength()/1000);
    } catch(Exception e){

    }
}
}
```

My intent is to start playing the song when opening the FXML via the initialize method.

Hope you guys can help.

Comment: Ugh.. `} catch(Exception e){

    }` Don't ignore exceptions! If not logging potential failures, at least dump the stack trace. E.G. `} catch(Exception e){
e.printStackTrace(); 
    }`

Comment: Isn't this some sort of duplicate? The issue of trying to open files from within jars has come up countless times. The file system doesn't include the interior of jar files. Use a URL to address these resources.

Comment: Found a duplicate from just last week. I know there are more going back several years. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50710703/why-wont-my-java-program-add-sound-even-with-wav-file/50729213#50729213

Answer (score 0):

Your music file should be inside of the 'src' file of your project for being deployed in JAR. And you should use "getResourceAsStream()" to get your sound file.

Comment: I've put it in my "AssetsLibrary"-folder under the src.
Where should I use the getRescourceAsStream()?

Comment: @AlexanderMicheelsenRol can you try this: AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/" + "filepath to sound file");

Comment: getResource() works perfectly well if you use a URL.

Answer (score 0):

When you launch your application from your IDE you can access to src file because your JVM execution Path is your project folder.

So you will understand that in a jar you don't have your project. In a Jar the execution path is the folder containing your jar and you will agree that even manually you don't found the folder src in this folder?

You need to consider your music track as resource and not as a file. I suggest you to read: [Location-Independent Access to Resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/lang/resources.html).

But in your case:

```
SomeClass.class.getResourceAsStream("relativePathfromSomeClasstoyourwavFile");
```

Comment: is it wrong to put the wav-file in the root folder or should it be in some sub folder to the src?

Comment: A best pratice is to use a dedicated package like %mybasepackage%.ressource with the ressoruces inside and a classes that handle the ressource with some static methods like getMainAudioTheme() that return the stream you search like this it accessible from anywhere in your programm easily( so yes in a sub package of src)

Comment: While this answer is along the right lines (for loading what is an embedded resource) I have a few recommendations: 1) A 'folder' is entirely a concept of a OS with a 'windowing system', what you are referring to is more accurately called a 'directory' (which is represented as a 'folder' on those OS'). 2) There are no folders or directories in a Jar, just resource paths. 3) `SomeClass.class` is usually better written as `this.getClass()` for the simple reason that the latter can only be used within the instance of a class - which will be more likely to get the context class loader intended ..

Comment: .. for application resources. The `SomeClass.class` version might be called in a `main(..)` method and risks getting the bootstrap class loader designed for the core APIs. 4) `"relativePath.."` No, it's safer to use `"/path/from/root/of/class/path"` which then becomes independent of the package of the loading class. The trick to getting that right is in the leading `/`. -- Having said that, **this** part is spot on ***"You need to consider your music track as resource and not as a file."***

Comment: Oh, and one trick I forgot to mention is that: 5) `getResource(..)` for an `URL` is sometimes safer than `getResourceAsStream(..)` for an `InputStream`. The reason is that Java Sound (in particular) requires a repositionable stream, whereas the stream from `getResourceAsStream(..)` often isn't. But provide the `Clip` class with an `URL` and it will do as needed to load the resource.

Comment: Singletons are ever a best practice as static methods ^^

Answer (score 0):

[Duplicate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50710703/why-wont-my-java-program-add-sound-even-with-wav-file/50729213#50729213)

OS file systems do not "see" into jar files. Use a URL instead, which can.

It is common to use a relative addressing scheme, and to place the audio in a resources folder of some sort. But you can also just put the audio in the same file as the class that is calling it. Or reference the root of your project with an "absolute" address (address starts with char "/"). Your choice.

The "duplicate" tag above has code examples.